# how to generate multiple accounts that all debit one single account at the end

Tags: accounts, addresses

I know that it is not possible to create multiple addresses that are bound to one ethereum wallet unlike in bitcoin.

However, I am trying to create an ico page where each user should get unique ether address into which he can do payment.

an example is this page: https://tokensale.amon.tech

[image]

I want to do the exact same thing. How is it possible programmatically to achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this. Why can you not let everyone use their "own" ethereum accounts?

Comment: @MathematicalRain sorry for being unclear in this point. (I edited the question now) What I meant was that each user gets unique ether address into which he transfers some ethers.

Comment: See this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/44252/33191 It is better (for transaction costs especially) to create a contract which handles this for you. Creating multiple addresses which allow you to take money out is going to cost you a significant amount of transaction costs.

Comment: @MathematicalRain great, thanks for the hint!! I will go for contracts then.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a contract unique to each user, which in turn deploys wallet accounts. But the cool thing with this is that you don't actually have to deploy those wallet accounts  until you want to or need to which can help you save significant gas costs. Why? Well that's because we can easily calculate the addresses of new contracts that will be generated by a contract.

Contract accounts start off with a nonce of 1, which is only increased during transactions from the contracts invoking the `create` opcode, so we can easily calculate addresses off-chain or on-chain. I wrote a contract that demonstrates this:

https://github.com/postables/Solidity-Modules/blob/master/Contracts/AddressGenerationCalculator.sol

Or if you don't want to go the whole contract route and don't care about centralization or security risks, you could generate the public-private key-pairs on your server, and create a web app to let people use their pre-generated wallets.